# Updating VB.Net Database With SQL Update Statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

so I got the update statement working and the record in the database is being updated. However the program is then throwing an error after the record is updated.

**Error**

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship.  Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again.

**Code**

```
        Dim variable As String
        dsConnectionM.Open()
        variable = "UPDATE Member SET MemberID = '" & Form3.tbid.Text & "', Forename = '" & Form3.tbfn.Text & "' "
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(variable, dsConnectionM)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dsConnectionM.Close()
```

[I don't know if this is normal but when ran a second Access file for the database is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD2lW.png)

[This shows the contents of "Member" in the databse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHzzK.png)

**EDITED**

I started using Parameters as I was advised now I get another error.

**ERROR**

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

**CODE**

```
Dim variable As String
dsConnectionM.Open()
variable = "UPDATE Member 
            SET Forename = @Forename,
                Surname = @Surname, 
                DOB = @DOB, 
                Section = @Section, 
                Postcode = @Postcode,
                HomeTel = @HomeTel, 
                MobileTel = @MobileTel, 
                AddressLine1 = @AddressLine1, 
                AddressLine2 = @AddressLine2, 
                City = @City, 
                EmailAddress = @EmailAddress, 
                P/GForename = @P/GForename, 
                P/GSurname = @P/GSurname
           WHERE MemberID = @MemberID"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(variable, dsConnectionM)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberID", Form3.tbid.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Forename", Form3.tbfn.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", Form3.tbsn.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", Form3.dtpdob.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Form3.tbsr.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", Form3.tbpc.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeTel", Form3.tbht.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileTel", Form3.tbmt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine1", Form3.tbal1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine2", Form3.tbal2.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", Form3.tbc.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", Form3.tbea.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P/GForename", Form3.tbpgfn.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P/GSurname", Form3.tbpgsn.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dsConnectionM.Close()
```

Comment: The error message is clear you are trying to set MemberID to a value already in the DB so will cause a Primary Key / Unique  Constrain Violation.

Comment: Both statements (it updates and throws an exception) cannot be true unless you have code calling that isolated snippet twice.  Also that has not been the correct way to create SQL for a long time now; use SQL Parameters.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You are probably asking the wrong question [**What is the XY problem?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: From MSDN: The OLE DB.NET Framework Data Provider uses positional parameters... The parameters must be listed in the same order as in the sql command.

Comment: Also your columns P/GForname & P/GSurname seem a bit suspect, Rather use the underscore P_GForname & P_GSurname to be safe.

Comment: @Vegito_ZA Your quote is incomplete so is wrong for this case `uses positional parameters that are marked with a question mark (?) instead of named parameters.`

Comment: If the problem was solve, close this question either by accepting one answer or writting your own answeer then create a new question for the new issue. Other wise all the coments and answer on the original question become irrelevant. And try to format the code a litle better, like this https://pastebin.com/uGwEYeiL

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza Access doesn't understand named parameters as far as I know, Or has something changed?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't `UPDATE` the `Pk` of a table. In your form `ID` should be read only. And if someone change some other value, you use the `ID` to find what row to `UPDATE`

```
variable = "UPDATE Member " &
           "SET Forename = '" & Form3.tbfn.Text & "' "
           "WHERE MemberID = '" & Form3.tbid.Text & "'
```

**And you need to use paramethers, other wise you are vulnerable to SQL Injection**

Comment: Making it update where memberId = whatever fixes the problem but now how would I be able to edit to memberID?

Comment: As I say, you shouldnt update `MemberID` in a table `Members` You probably doing something wrong. Maybe try to share and example of what you need and what your result should be. Maybe a picture of your form.

Comment: Hi all, I updated the code and am getting another error.

Comment: I wouldnt name a parameter using slash caracter `/` try with underscore `_`

Comment: But that is how it is in the database.

Comment: That was a suggestion. Try removing parameters until you find the culprit assignment.

Comment: It only seems to work when there is only 1 value in the SET statement :/

Comment: doesnt make sense ... you mean anyone alone work, but two doesnt? did you try different pair?

Comment: Hi, I managed to find the problem with it being "Section", no clue why. But now I am having another problem. I have edited the original post.

Comment: If the problem was solve, close this question and create a new one. Other wise all the coments and answer on the original question become irrelevant. And try to format the code a litle better, like this https://pastebin.com/uGwEYeiL

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your query is meant to change the Forename field of the member having a particular ID.

In this case your query should look like this

```
UPDATE Member SET Forename = '" & Form3.tbfn.Text & "' where MemberID = '" & Form3.tbid.Text & "'
```